# Database Error CodeIgniter 3.0.6

Tags: database, codeigniter

Have updated application that was previous running on code ignitor version 3.0 to 3.0.6. On my local server its working fine but when I upload to ipage I get database error. Gone through the manual tried solution here on stack overflow unfortunately non works for me.

[link to error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEiYh.png)

**DB connection**

```
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => 'myipagehost',
'username' => 'myusername',
'password' => 'mypass',
'database' => 'mydatabase',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
```

**Controller for landing**

```
class Landing extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}
public function index()
{   
    // $this->load->view('template/frontheader');
    $this->load->view('landing/index');
    // $this->load->view('template/frontfooter');
}
function internships()
{
    $this->load->view('landing/internship');
}
function cities()
{
    $this->load->view('landing/cities');
}
function categories()
{
    $this->load->view('landing/categories');
}

function policy()
{
    $this->load->view('landing/policy');
}

function support()
{
    $this->load->view('template/frontheader');
    $this->load->view('landing/support');
    $this->load->view('template/frontfooter');
}
function termsandcondition()
{
    $this->load->view('landing/termaandcondition');
}
function aboutus()
{   
    $this->load->view('template/frontheader');
    $this->load->view('landing/aboutus');
    $this->load->view('template/frontfooter');
}
function partner()
{   
    $this->load->view('template/frontheader');
    $this->load->view('landing/partners');
    $this->load->view('template/frontfooter');

}
function faq()
{
    $this->load->view('landing/faq');
}

function contact()
{
    $this->load->view('landing/contactus');
}
```

}

Comment: show your code of controller & database.php

Comment: @RejoanulAlam Unpadded with controller and db string.

Comment: `'hostname' => 'myipagehost',` it should `'hostname' => 'localhost',`

Comment: @RejoanulAlam not working I tried that too.

Comment: Check this out: http://serverfault.com/questions/385378/mysql-connect-the-server-requested-authentication-method-unknown-to-the-clien

Answer (score 0):

You could ask your host to disable old_passwords, but if it's a shared database system, they're likely to be unwilling to do so.

Comment: Thanks @subash I try to talk to them, is there a work around for that if they decline?